# Почему альфаканал в .bmp (bitmap) криво отображается в контекстном меню?

Tags: dll, shell, menu, icon, photoshop

Пытаюсь вшить в .dll данную иконку, но если в редакторах и вьюверах с альфа-каналом данного .bmp все в порядке, то в контекстном меню она почему-то отображается криво (см. скриншот - "Создать файл контр.."). Что я делаю не так?

Может ли кто-то помочь? Вот сами файлы оригинал и отредактированный bitmap:

https://yadi.sk/i/gyFa6W1lyT1k9w (Оригинал)
https://yadi.sk/i/9RJTWfjGeaYE0A (Сделанный бмп)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Формат bmp не поддерживает прозрачность. По крайней мере раньше так было. Программы могут просто не учитывать или не понимать альфаканал. Для прозрачности есть формат png или для иконок ico.

Comment: gif так же поддерживает прозрачность, но не все библиотеки. gif выигрывает у png только при наличии малого к-ва цветов.

Comment: png бывает тоже с малым количеством цветов. Даже с полупрозрачной градацией png может иметь мало цветов, например 4-битный. Это тоже не везде работает, но довольно широко, браузеры и фотошоп например поддерживают это. Есть прога Pngyu для сжатия png с полупрозрачностью, позволяющая сильно уменьшить размер, теряя битность.

Comment: Я хочу дополнить что gif тоже поддерживает прозрачность согласно стандарту.